# How to install RStudio in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, rstudio

I had recently installed Ubuntu MATE 32-bit on my Raspberry Pi 3B+. When I go through the steps in any installation process for RStudio, I find out it doesn't work or it's not what I am looking for. I have done a ton of research and YouTube-watching for this and yet it doesn't work. And if you might wanna help, please don't give any link. I have probably been through all of the links. And I need a detailed, step-by-step process explaining what each and everything does. BTW I only need RStudio I already got R Base.

Comment: How are you trying to install it and what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @NasirRiley Thanks for reaching out to me! I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I tried by downloading it and opening it with the installer. The installation starts but then it says it has some problems related to 'amd64'. The other ways to install(The terminal basically) also has the same issues. I have even tried 64 bit ubuntu.

Comment: By installer, what tool are you referring to? `apt`? `dpkg`?

Comment: Some software I dunno  it starts with a GP

Answer (score 0):

You have already installed R-base which is the first step. Download the .deb file for RStudio from here https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb, and then install it with `apt`:

```
apt-get install ./rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb
```

Comment: hmm i'll see if this works..